# Win 7 started optimizing folders to general items. How do I get it to stop?

Tags: windows-7

This started happening a few days ago, maybe with an update.
I don't like how the new default- `General Items` groups items, and would like items to use Documents as a default, but no matter how often I set it it goes back to General items sooner or later.

Is there a way to put an end to it? it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Folders options > Second tab > Reset

Set a folder as you want it to show, return to folders option > second tab > Apply to folders